# Bidirectional Drag and Drop/Shared Clipboard is not working with VirtualBox Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I used VirtualBox version 5.1.6 to install Kali Linux 2016.2 x64 as a VM.

I made sure my system was up-to-date:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

I grabbed the VirtualBox Guest Additions:

`sudo apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11`

Set up the following functionality:

**Settings(Host + S) -> General -> Advanced**:

**Shared Clipboard**: *Bidirectional*

**Drag and Drop**: *Bidirectional*

Then I rebooted the system; `reboot`.

Tried to drag and drop a directory from the Host to the Guest and nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm running Kali-Linux-2017.1-vbox-amd64 and updated && upgraded it and faced the same issue as you. I fixed it by adding the following command at the end of the ~/.bashrc file:

```
# Enable VirtualBox Clipboard 
VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Type in the command to your terminal or restart it (the terminal) and your clipboard will work once again.

Comment: Occasionally VirtualBox's shared clipboard will stop working. For me I notice that it stops working after my host OS (Mac) password protected screensaver starts. While rebooting the guest OS will resolve the situation, killing and restarting the VBoxClient --clipboard command will get the clipboard capability back.

ps -ef | grep VBoxClient | grep clip
kill -9 [the PIDs]
VBoxClient --clipboard

Comment: This doesn't work. In addition it produces error.

Comment: The instructions from user503821 work. You need to run `ps -ef | grep VBoxClient | grep clip`, then observe the PIDs, then run the `kill` and `VBoxClient --clipboard` commands with `sudo` or as root.